# Prove equality in discrete maths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So I want to prove why those two are equal but I'don't know how. 
$\exists x(A(x) \implies B(x))$ and $\exists x A(x) \implies \exists x B(x)$

I have a theory but I am not sure if that's the right way. First find their negatives:

1st: $\lnot(\exists x(A(x) \implies B(x)))  \iff \forall x(A(x) \wedge \lnot B(x))$

2nd: $\lnot(\exists x A(x) \implies \exists x B(x)) \iff \forall x A(x) \wedge ∀x \lnot B(x)$

then set $\lnot B(x)$ as $C(x)$ and then the proof is rather easy. I think though even if what I have written above is correct its kinda a roundabout way and there's got to be a better, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equal. Think about what each implication says when $A(x)$ is "$x=1$" and $B(x)$ is "$x=0$" .

Comment: Shoot, you are right but yet again how to I prove that?

Comment: What is there to prove? A counterexample is a proof that an assertion is false.